# (Tortoise) SVN Merge from foreign repository is not compatible with mergeinfo modification

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN to handle versioning and for some time now (but not from the beginning) it has stopped adding the `mergeinfo` properties when I merge. What I have done:

- **Unchecked** the `Ignore ancestry` checkbox during merges
- Made sure that both repo urls are *all lowercase* since it seems there are casing issues
- Tried to merge using the `--record-only` flag and I'm getting this error: `Merge from foreign repository is not compatible with mergeinfo modification`
- Updated TortoiseSVN from 1.9.5 to 1.14
- Checked with my colleagues, no one has this problem which means the issue doesn't stem from the repository service

I've looked around and the only reference to the error is attributing it to bad path casing which is not my case. I have a clean checkout of the branch I want to merge into as well, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

check your working copy url.
url case-sensitive problem in my case.

Comment: For me a new clean checkout worked. The url of the defective WC seemed correct to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).